# Summation of Double Exponential Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum, summation-method

Is there any known closed form or tight bound analysis (big-O or big-$\Theta$) for $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} 2^{2^i}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that
$$
2^{2^n}\le \sum_{i=0}^n 2^{2^i}\le 2^{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}}2^k=2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}+1}-1\le 2^{2^n}+2\cdot 2^{2^{n-1}}=2^{2^n}(1+2\cdot 2^{-2^{n-1}})
$$
This shows that your sum is eventually between $2^{2^n}$ and $(1+\epsilon)2^{2^n}$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a follow-up question: by **any $\epsilon > 0$**, you mean that for any such parameter, there as a large enough **$n$**, right?

Comment: @Nima That is correct. The time you have to wait depends on $\epsilon$. Specifically, you need $n\ge \log \log \frac1\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

If within constants is fine, then here's an easy proof that it is $\Theta(2^{2^n})$. The idea is that $2^{2^i}$ grows faster than exponential, so it should be that the largest term in the sum dominates the sum itself up to a constant.

The lower bound is obvious. For the upper bound, we show that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^i}\leq 2\cdot 2^{2^n}$ by induction. Start with the inductive hypothesis. Then,
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^i} &\leq 2\cdot 2^{2^n}\leq 2^{2^n}\cdot 2^{2^n} = 2^{2^{n+1}}.
\end{align*}
Now adding $2^{2^{n+1}}$ on both sides allows us to conclude as desired.